# why decorate Jinja2 instances with @webapp2.cached_property

Tags: caching, properties, jinja2, webapp2

The webapp2 site (http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html) has a tutorial on how to use `webapp2_extras.jinja2`, and the code is below.

My question is: why cache the `webapp2_extras.jinja2.Jinja2` instance return by `return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)`? I checked the code of `@webapp2.cached_property` and found that it caches the `Jinja2` instance in a instance of `BaseHandler`, which will be destroyed after the request, so why bother to cache it? Did I miss something here?

```
import webapp2

from webapp2_extras import jinja2

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        # Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry.
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, _template, **context):
        # Renders a template and writes the result to the response.
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)
```

Comment: Funny you´ve asked that... just had a look at the same and can´t get the point either... There is a point to cached_property of course for things used more than once in one request...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.cached_property) you can find the documentation about `cached_property`.

The `BaseHandler` class will be later on called often. My understanding is that to avoid the overhead of calling `jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)` each time, such reference is evaluated the first time only, and then returned many times later on, i.e. every time a view is called.

To see this happen in code, see [this](https://github.com/fRuiApps/cpfthw/blob/master/webapp2/views.py) example, where each view is derived from the same `BaseHandler` class.